# Oracle APEX error on insert row - ORA-00001: exclusive restriction (ASCHEMAXXXXX.Table_name_PK) violated

Tags: triggers, oracle-apex, primary-key

Why am I getting this error when trying to insert a new row in the APEX app?

> `ORA-00001: exclusive restriction (ASCHEMAXXXXX.Table_name_PK) violated`

There is a dynamic action on page load to get the next value for one of the fields.

I tried to create a sequence and use it on the primary key, but got `.nextvalue not declared`.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't explain what that dynamic action actually does, but - it seems it doesn't do what you meant it would. Besides, what kind of a page is it? Form? Interactive Grid? Something else? Consider posting as many information as possible; otherwise, it is difficult to guess what might be going on.

---

Saying that you *tried to use a sequence*, then: if your database version supports it, why wouldn't you switch to an **identity** column and let database take care about PK values? For example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id          number generated always as identity primary key,
  3     name        varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL>
```

---

Another option is to use sequence + trigger combination:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id     number primary key,
  3     name   varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq_test;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := seq_test.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had previously inserted data programmatically, which included specific primary key (PK) values.
Consequently, the trigger did not increment the PK sequence number.
Therefore, when I attempted to add a row via the form, it tried to assign a PK number that was already in use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).